# Python/openssl requests unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (works in WSL vscode debug, does not work outside of it)

Tags: python, python-requests, openssl, vscode-debugger

Experiencing issues with OpenSSL disabling renegotiation on a university website.

Relevant info:

OS: WSL Ubuntu, VScode WSL extension, Python v3.10, OpenSSL v3 (site in question: hrpd.unt.edu)

I am trying to do some basic web requests in Python using requests_html and have encountered various SSL issues (verification issues). I fixed that by downloading the certificate chain from my browser and passing that as the verify= parameter in my POST request.

The issue is that when running my script in VSCode debug mode everything works as expected (after setting up a custom openSSL.cnf allowing renegotiation and setting OPENSSL_CONFIG to the absolute path of my custom configuration load_dotenv() my .env) and I get the intended data behind the login page. If I do not run it in debug mode OR manually “export” the environment variable, I get a SSL error that legacy renegotiation is disabled. I’ve verified that the correct python is being run (the one inside my virtual environment) using “which”.

I have verified that the environment is updated properly by printing the environment variables before the login request is made, and the openssl path is set correctly. Even with that, it does not work outside of debug mode. The issue affects a regular WSL Ubuntu shell and the ones that VSC creates from dragging up from the bottom. It also does not work on my dedicated Ubuntu 22.04 server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.